# Why this portion use in flutter. Actually I try to know the basic working material of this portion

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Here is the portion which I didn't understand.

```
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
```

> I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onMapCreated:` is a callback that will be called when the map is created as the name suggests, and it'll pas the `GoogleMapController` for you. If that field is optional, you may not need to do anything.

If you need to use the controller upon the map creation, pass a function that satisfies the definition. You can pass a function like you did, or you can write a function outside and then pass that function name as long as it satisfies the definition such:

```dart
void onMapCreatedFunction(GoogleMapController controller) {
 // do something with the controller if you need to .. 
}
```

then on the object, pass that function:

```dart
onMapCreated: onMapCreatedFunction,
```

This is style of callback is similar to the `builder` method in `ListView` as an example.

Comment: Got this.
Thank you